# how do I make this page work it just redirects to homepage

Tags: php, sql

I am making e-commerce site and add to basket script not doing anything 
   I expect it to insert data into shopping basket from products page that is working perfectly fine. Please have a look and help me figure it out.. it is not giving any syntax error or parse error it just dont do anything and when I click buy it just redirect me to homepage

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();
require("db.php");
require("functions.php");
$validid = pf_validate_number($_GET['id'], "redirect", $config_basedir);
$prodsql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = " . $_GET['id'] . ";";
$prodres = mysqli_query($prodsql);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($prodres);
$prodrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($prodres);
if($numrows == 0)
{     
  header("Location: " . $config_basedir);
} else {
  if($_POST['submit'])
  {
    if($_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM'])
    {
      $itemsql = "INSERT INTO orderitems(order_id, product_id, quantity) VALUES("
                 . $_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM'] . ", "
                 . $_GET['id'] . ", "
                 . $_POST['amountBox'] . ")";
      mysqli_query($itemsql);
    } else {
      if($_SESSION['SESS_LOGGEDIN'])
      {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO orders(customer_id, registered, date) VALUES("
               . $_SESSION['SESS_USERID'] . ", 1, NOW())";
        mysqli_query($sql);
        session_register("SESS_ORDERNUM");
        $_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM'] = mysqli_insert_id();
        $itemsql = "INSERT INTO orderitems(order_id, product_id, quantity) VALUES("
                   . $_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM']
                   . ", " . $_GET['id'] . ", "
                   . $_POST['amountBox'] . ")";
        mysqli_query($itemsql);
      } else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO orders(registered, date, session) VALUES("
               . "0, NOW(), '" . session_id() . "')";
        mysqli_query($sql);
        session_register("SESS_ORDERNUM");
        $_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM'] = mysqli_insert_id();
        $itemsql = "INSERT INTO orderitems(order_id, product_id, quantity) VALUES("
                   . $_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM'] . ", " . $_GET['id'] . ", " 
                   . $_POST['amountBox'] . ")";
        mysqli_query($itemsql);
      }
    }
    $totalprice = $prodrow['price'] * $_POST['amountBox'] ;
    $updsql = "UPDATE orders SET total = total + "
              . $totalprice . " WHERE id = "
              . $_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM'] . ";";
    mysqli_query($updres);
    header("Location: " . $config_basedir . "showcart.php");
  } else {
    require("header.php");
    echo "<form action='addtobasket.php?id="
         . $_GET['id'] . "' method='POST'>";
    echo "<table cellpadding='10'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    if(empty($prodrow['image'])) 
    {
      echo "<td><img src='./productimages/dummy.jpg' width='50' alt='"
           . $prodrow['name'] . "'></td>";
    } else {
      echo "<td><img src='./productimages/" . $prodrow['image']
           . "' width='50' alt='" . $prodrow['name']
           . "'></td>";
    }
      echo "<td>" . $prodrow['name'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>Select Quantity <select name='amountBox'>";
      for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++)
      {
        echo "<option>" . $i . "</option>";
      }
      echo "</select></td>";
      echo "<td><strong>&pound;"
           . sprintf('%.2f', $prodrow['price'])
           . "</strong></td>";
      echo "<td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add to basket'></td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      echo "</table>";
      echo "</form>";
   }
}
require("footer.php");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

Comment: What have you done so far to try and debug this? (Should you have no idea what the most basic debugging techniques/steps are, then you should probably go inform yourself, _before_ you try to create an e-commerce site, just saying.)

Comment: can u help to debug

Comment: Please describe what _you_ have done/tried so far first of all.

Comment: I enabled error reporting e_all but no luck, I checked online tools for syntax error but nothing

Comment: Then the next steps is to check return values of function/method calls, and to verify whether variables contain what you think they should at certain points. var_dump is a good tool to make relevant debug outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two redirects that makes your user return to your home page

first:

```
$validid = pf_validate_number($_GET['id'], "redirect", $config_basedir);
```

make sure `$_GET['id]` has valid value

second:

```
$prodsql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = " . $_GET['id'] . ";";
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($prodres);
// ...
if($numrows == 0)
{     
  header("Location: " . $config_basedir);
}
```

check your query in this line:

```
$prodsql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = " . $_GET['id'] . ";";
```

make sure it returns not an empty results ( `$numrows == 0` )

Test it first on your DBMS front-end

Comment: thanks I changed it now it working but giving more errors

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sae/worldz/addtobasket.php on line 9

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sae/worldz/addtobasket.php on line 10

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sae/worldz/addtobasket.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: submit in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sae/worldz/addtobasket.php on line 17

Comment: Ashking you can google the solution for that error very easily. Also check the documentation for mysqli_query and check what parameters you need to provide (hint: you forgot to include the connection object)

Comment: i solved mysqli_query error please help me with this one I cannot figure it out


 mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sae/worldz/addtobasket.php on line 10

Comment: Again Google it...there are plenty of suggestions. Basically it means your query failed somehow. You have to find out why. You can either make mysqli throw exceptions, or you can use the mysqli_error() function to get a description. All of this is very well documented online, you can use your initiative to research it

Comment: feel free to make another question, but first make it sure that your question doesn't have answer yet, you can do searching as @ADyson says